# action bar menu color changed by SearchView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, action, searchview

[image]

I am using an menu in `action bar` with a `SearchView` in it , the `xml` defined as:

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:onClick="search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="search"
    />
```

but from the attached image(the first menu and the 3rd menu has the same image), the search image which should has the white color as the left icon has another background color similiar to light gray. Could any one tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the solution is, but I can tell you why it is happening.  The SearchView uses its own icon to display on the action bar.  So, when you set the icon in the XML it gets overriden by the default SearchView icon.  I'd be interested in anyone's answer to this because this is a problem I actually ran into myself without being able to find an answer.

Comment: yes I also find that. It seems that there is no simple workaround for that. So my choice is to let it be by now, until I find a good way